# ros2-crazyswarm2

Tags: ros2

We'd like to use crazyswarm2 packages. However we got below error about `motion_capture` stuff. How to figure out that problem, thanks.

```
ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/Documents/crazyswarm2$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash 

ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/Documents/crazyswarm2$ colcon build

Starting >>> crazyflie_interfaces
Finished <<< crazyflie_interfaces [7.81s]                     
Starting >>> crazyflie_py
Starting >>> crazyflie                     
Starting >>> crazyflie_sim
Finished <<< crazyflie_py [0.87s]                                             
Starting >>> crazyflie_examples
Finished <<< crazyflie_sim [1.11s]                            
--- stderr: crazyflie                                                                       
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findmotion_capture_tracking_interfaces.cmake" in
  CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package
  configuration file provided by "motion_capture_tracking_interfaces", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "motion_capture_tracking_interfaces" with any of the following names:

    motion_capture_tracking_interfacesConfig.cmake
    motion_capture_tracking_interfaces-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "motion_capture_tracking_interfaces" to
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "motion_capture_tracking_interfaces_DIR" to a
  directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "motion_capture_tracking_interfaces" provides a separate development
  package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


---
Failed   <<< crazyflie [1.43s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< crazyflie_examples [0.79s]                           

Summary: 3 packages finished [9.71s]
  1 package failed: crazyflie
  1 package aborted: crazyflie_examples
  1 package had stderr output: crazyflie
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely that your `motion_capture_tracking_interfaces` package did not compile/is not present.

If the package is present in the same workspace, *i.e.*, if your `src` directory looks like the following:

```
src
|-> crazyflie
|    | . . .
|-> crazyflie_examples
|    | . . .
|-> crazyflie_py
|    | . . . 
|-> motion_capture_tracking_interfaces
```

Then you can try compiling the `motion_capture_tracking_interfaces` package first by using `colcon build --packages-select motion_capture_tracking_interfaces`.

You should also examine if you made an error *(maybe a typo)* in the `find_packages` section of the CMakeLists.txt of the package is calling the correct package name. I have had multiple instances of this error where I mistakenly called `find_package(<project>-mgs REQUIRED)` which led me to this error.

***P.S.:*** On the off-chance that you might need to actually write the `Config.cmake` yourself, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65045150/how-to-fix-could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-error-in-cmake) answer on StackOverflow is one of the best explanations I have come across.

Comment: I think you were right. Because I run `colcon build` in a different directory (**ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/Documents/crazyswarm2$** colcon build). So, it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have any reputation yet to comment I'll just add this as a separate answer. The documentation for the crazyswarm2 project is here with the installation instructions, to make sure that the packages are in the right folders.

https://imrclab.github.io/crazyswarm2/installation.html

Motion_capture_tracking_interfaces is part of a different package on which crazyswarm2 depends on.

This question was also asked on the project github discussions as well: [ros2-crazyswarm2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104512/ros2-crazyswarm2/104544#104544), for more background information.

(I'm a co-maintainer at crazyswarm2).